# Extend background time on xamarin ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, background

I am trying to do a task that runs indefinitely in a background mode in xamarin ios, but the task takes only 30 seconds to kill the app when it is send to a second plane, so I really do not know how to extend this time in order to receive that information.

This is the method that launches the background task:

```
public async void ActivateHeartbeat()
        {
            
           
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                taskID = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("APPLICATION GOT KILLED");
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskID);
                    

                });

                while (true)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Background time remaining: " + UIApplication.SharedApplication.BackgroundTimeRemaining);

                    int sent = SendTCP(data);
                    if (sent > 0) Console.WriteLine("Sent Heartbeat.");
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);

                }

            });

        }
```

I have already read all the documentation that Microsoft is offering, but it did not help for me. How can I increase that background time?

Result of console when the app is pushed to second plane (minimizing the app on an iPhone):

```
 Background time remaining: 25.9390514166444
 Sent Heartbeat.
 Background time remaining: 15.8512012083665
 Sent Heartbeat.
 Background time remaining: 5.76157358335331
 Sent Heartbeat.
 APPLICATION GOT KILLED
 APPLICATION GOT KILLED
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance,
Raúl.

Comment: You cannot execute in the background indefinitely. Apps have limited background execution time.

Comment: So, what should be another solution to implement a background task for extend this time, at least, for 10 minutes?

Comment: It just isn't possible. 30 second is all you get. You need to come up with some other strategy. What are you wanting to do for 10 minutes?

Comment: I am trying to send TCP heartbeat to a open server, which is listening for an incoming call (not using VOiP, only TCP connection, as it was a chat or whatever). It is listening for commands such as receiving call, acceepted call, decline call, so it has to be always listening for those commands.

Comment: That isn't going to work on iOS. If you want to send those events to your iOS app then your server should use silent push notifications.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685525

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that Apple is so strict about hardware resources occupied by App, not to mention App in the background state. When App enter the background state, it will soon be suspended by the OS, unless you apply for permisson from OS.

The following image is from XCode Capabilities. These modes can run in the Background Modes.

[image]

Seems that you couldn't directly run your app in the background mode.

However, some articles extend the background time by playing blank videos as audio can be played in Background modes. That means we have to play blank audio in the background task. You could refer to [Unlimited Backgrounding on iOS](https://yifan.lu/2013/12/17/unlimited-backgrounding-on-ios/). But i have no idea if Apple will approve this app on Apple Store.

Hope my answer makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know any example that uses Push Notifications to avoid this problem in xamarin ios? As far as I know, if I send push notifications (remote) to the device, it can keep some code alive again. I´ve found Shiny package, that could be useful, but I do not find demos using it in xamarin.ios.

Comment: You could refer to [Remote Notifications (iOS 7 and Greater)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/updating-an-application-in-the-background#remote-notifications-ios-7-and-greater). DidReceiveRemoteNotification method is Invoked by operating system when your application received a remote notification.